# Converting an Experian (Geoconcept) file to GPS coordinates

Tags: polygon, coordinate-system, convert, gps

I'm working with a file containing [Experian](http://www.experian.fr/) data which was used in [Geoconcept](http://fr.geoconcept.com/).

The file describes a serie of microzones, that is polygons. Unfortuntely the coordinates system is hard to understand:

```
    2116944 602039  2116760 602084  2116700 
602124  2116670 602169  2116600 602240  2116420 602269  2116320 602360
```

How can I convert the data to GPS coordinates?

Comment: http://multiplans.net/conversion_LambertWGS84.html 2116944 602039 works out to be https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=46.05270,2.36289&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&hnear=0x47f9f06902a50243:0xd0a723d655514b69,46.05270,2.36289&gl=ca&t=h&z=15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first polygon is in the area of 46N 4E, it is probably in NTF Lambert II (EPSG 27572). That is sometimes used for countrywide French data. It doesn't appear to be Lambert93 which is another coordinate reference system that is used for countrywide data in France. The coordinates are given in northing,easting order.